# Links in navbar not directing to appropriate page

Tags: php, html, navigation

If I go to `index.php` it is working for the first time, but cannot go to other page from index page.

> Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. The
>   link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please
>   inform the author of that page about the error.

```
<nav class="navbar" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-backyard">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar-scroll" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-backyard"> 
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="z-index:100"> 
                  <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li> 
                  <li><a href="about_china/about_china.php">About China</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Scholarships</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Chinese Government Scholarships</a>
                            <a href="#">Local Government Scholarships</a>
                            <a href="#">Confucius Institute Scholarships</a>
                            <a href="#">School Scholarships</a>
                            <a href="#">Enterprise Scholarships</a>
                            <a href="#">Other Scholarships</a>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Universities & Programs</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Search Universities & Regions</a>
                            <a href="#">Search Categories & Programs</a>
                        </li>   
                      </ul>
                   </li>    
                  <li><a href="alumni/alumni.php">Alumni</a></li>
              </ul>

        </div>      
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Prefix all your `href` values with a forward slash. I think that they should all be relative to the server root. The way you have it now, they're relative to the current URL path

Comment: if you're having folders like alumni & about_china then rename the file in the folder to index.php & link will be just `href="/alumni/"`

Comment: @JosephStalin made the same thing but still is not working

Comment: okay, then what is happening when you click the link?

Comment: @JosephStalin the same thing like object not found

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<li><a href="about_china/about_china.php">About China</a></li>
```

to this

```
<li><a href="/about_china/about_china.php">About China</a></li>
```

do the same with other links.

If the link is in form or `some/path` it will be **relative to current location** so for example if we are on `example.com/dashboard`, this link will point to `example.com/dashboard/some/path`. If you use link like `/some/path` on the other hand it will be absolute, and effective url will be like `exampl.com/some/path`

Answer (score 0):

The requested URL was not found on this server because of your href path is not correct or file is not present on given path

Try below steps.

Move "about_china.php" file where "index.php" is located and try below path in href.

```
<a href="about_china.php">
```

Answer (score 0):

This error might have occurred due to below:

1. Server might have interrupted. (Check Localhost or Apache server carefully)
2. Path link might be broken.(Check links carefully)
3. File not existing. (Link is not existed)
4. Directory path location is incorrect.

try using notation dots to linking backward.

if file exist in current directory write like below :

```
<li><a href="./about_china.php">About China</a></li>
```

Or

if file exist in one level up directory ex: "about_china/about_china.php"  write like below :

```
<li><a href="../about_china.php">About China</a></li>
```

Or

if file exist in two level up directory ex: "parent/about_china/about_china.php"  write like below :

```
<li><a href="../../about_china.php">About China</a></li>
```

Or

If notation dots does not work efficiently in your situation  please give the absolute path link :

```
<li><a href="parent/about_china/about_china.php">About China</a></li>
```

Thanks ! 
Hope it helps you !!